# Did 'evil' exist even before Satan?

Tags: sin, satan

"Your heart became proud on account of your beauty, and you corrupted your wisdom because of your splendor. So I threw you to the earth; I made a spectacle of you before kings" - Ezekiel 28:17

This verse can be considered as a quote about the first 'sin' in the entire biblical timeline. After the occurrence of which, Satan was formed. I would like to know more details about the evil 'pride' indicated in this verse, which existed even before Satan. Does this 'evil' have a personality? How it was capable of running its root into a splendorous and powerful creation of God - Lucifer?

Comment: Augustine of Hippo would argue that evil is not a thing in and of itself, but rather the lack of good. As such, he would not argue that it began to exist ever, simply that there was a point when there was a perceptible lack of goodness that we call evil- but there would be no way to correlate that with Satan- the Accuser of the Brethren...